Spring Data jpa querydsl findall query performance is too slow
I have the table test with id int, name varchar, testName varchar with testName foreign key of test 1 table with column name in test1 table.test1 name has 3 values inserted with exact, regex, range. so test table holds 3 million record when doing findAll (pageable) with sortBy testName as it is foreign key relationship takes around 40 seconds. how i can optimise in spring data jpa, hibernate to get within 5 seconds.
Create table test (
Id int primary key,
name varchar(255),
testName varchar(255) not null,
key fk_test1_name(testName),
Constraint 'fk_test1_name foreign key('testName) references test1(name));


Create table test1(
name varchar(255) primary key);

In test1 we have inserted values exact, regex, range.
In test table we have 3 million records so i am using findAll (Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable) in querydsl of spring data jpa and hibernate. it is taking around 40 seconds if i do sortBy of testName. I want to make it in 5 seconds. how to tune it? In test table we will have other foreign key fields also which i did not mention. so sortBy will be dynamic as per the foreign key fields also. I am using mariadb database as mysql.

You don't, loading 3 million records isn't going to happen in 5 seconds. It involves memory management, creating objects, etc. if you are unlucky and have created wrong relationships in your entities you even get 3 million additional individual queries. In short don't load 3 million rows into memory as that will always be slow. 1 thing you can do to improve is to update the jdbc fetch size (default is 10) to something like 1000, this will reduce the network roundtrips.

I am fetching as pagination of 20 size with sortBy testName, it tooks 40 seconds .Sp for that I need 5 secs and how it can be tuned

Why use pagination if you need everything, use a cursor (streaming) instead of paging. Paging will be slow in the end as the farther you get the longer it takes to retrieve the results.

looks like findall makes a count, so it will have a look at all records, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37254385/querydsl-springdata-jpa-findall-how-to-avoid-count
